# svndumpfilter2 vs svndumpfilter3

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I keep hitting the memory issues in svndumpfilter2 (someone checked in 4Gb of binaries into my subversion...) and it is just crashing on that particular commit.

```
svnadmin dump repo/ | python svndumpfilter2 repo/ keep/this/path > myrepo.dump
```

It crashes each time

So I tried svndumpfilter3, latest copy from the [git repo](https://github.com/bmwiedemann/svndumpfilter3)
When I looked at the latest copy of svndumpfilter3 - it is looking for an environment variable "MODULE".

I cant find this documented, and when I set it, the dump doesnt seem to work.

Has anyone got an updated guide on svndumpfilter3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the zerofilefix branch from https://github.com/bmwiedemann/svndumpfilter3.git - it worked for me.

The zerofilefix branch does not contain the module environment variable code. That code is a recent addition and seems to be a local environment variable for the author.  I could not find any references to it in python or subversion documentation either.